# How to merge insert combine multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, insert

I have multiple tables (12 for each month) that have 3 columns each ("code", "test_name", "value")

Example:

---

```
January
code | test_name | value
0001   name1       17
0002   name2       45
0005   name5       12
```

---

```
February
code | test_name | value
0001   name1       3
0002   name2       7
0004   name4       13
```

---

```
March
code | test_name | value
0001   name1       6
0006   name6       32
0007   name7       41
```

---

How do I merge or insert or combine it in sql into one table that would look like this:

```
Year
code | test_name | January | February | March | ...
0001   name1       17        3          6
0002   name2       45        7          0
0003   name3       0         0          0
0004   name4       0         13         0
0005   name5       12        0          0
0006   name6       0         0          32
0007   name7       0         0          41
```

Comment: I went with @Gordon Linoff solution and it worked perfectly, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallel tables (those with the same columns) are usually a sign of poor design.  A single table with different columns is generally preferable.

You can do what you want using `union all` and `group by`:

```
select code, test_name,
       max(jan) as jan, max(feb) as feb, max(mar) as mar
from ((select code, test_name, value as Jan, NULL as Feb, NULL as Mar
       from January
      ) union all
      (select code, test_name, NULL as Jan, value as Feb, NULL as Mar
       from February
      ) union all
      (select code, test_name, NULL as Jan, NULL as Feb, value as Mar
       from March
      )
     ) ct
group by code, test_name;
```